# Kendo UI autocomplete dynamically loading dBdata when typing

Tags: dynamic, kendo-ui, autocomplete, datasource, loading

I am writing a kendo UI autocomplete widget. The requirement is **EACH TIME** when I type a letter after "minLength", the dataSource need to be dynamically loaded from dB **EVERYTIME**. One problem is that, when the dataSource load successfully in the first time, it stops loading data.

The code snippet is:

```
var data;
function getDataFromDb(){
    // some code to grab dummyData from dB ...
    return dummyData;
}
$("#someInputText").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 2,
    dataTextField: "someField",
    dataSource: getDataFromDb(),
    filter: "startswith"
});
```

Thanks a lot.

More details on the post. In my situation, I don't use the readOption. The data comes from another ajax call like:

```
var data [];
//fire this ajax call when input string length comes to 4...
$.ajax({url: "some working url", success: function(result){
    var data = result;
    startKendoAutoComplete();
  }
});


function startKendoAutoComplete(){
    if( !$.isEmptyObject(data)) // set a breakPoint, have data
    {
        $("#inputText").kendoAutoComplete({
           minLength: 4,
           dataSource : data,
           ...
        });
    }
}
```

Also, the ajax call will be fired when the input string length comes to 4. However, the KendoAutoComplete doesn't start working....

Thanks a lot for your sugesstion.

Comment: I don't understand, you're asking to load data dynamically from DB every time the user type something, but initialise the data only once and you don't want to use the readOptions... how can you reload data if you don't fetch anything from the server after the initial load?

Comment: The reason to dynamically load day from DB is that, the data is so huge, nearly a million rows from an real application. It is impossible/infeasible/prohibited to load the data initially. Also, the only way to load data is via a given ajax call given. Thanks a lot for your all responses.

Comment: And how do you expect to reload some filtered data without fetching anything after the initial load?

Comment: Filtered data is just like, if I entered four letters, the data size is feasible to handle. (Currently, I tried if I entered three letters and load initially data. So huge/slow, and then Kendo autoComplete start working when I enter the fourth letter. ) And then, I need the Kendo autoComplete start working when I typed in the the fourth letter. Thanks for your helps. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you init your `dataSource` with an array of object, your widget will work with this array only.

The first thing you'll have to create an dataSource object and set the `serverFiltering` property to true.  Then, if you don't specify an url where the data will be fetched, you set you own `transport.read` function and from there you'll be able to implement your own logic.  The `read` function will receive the `readOption` which will include all the relevant information to query tour data (top / skip / filter / sort ...).  The `readOptions` will also provide a `success` function that should be used to return the value:

```
dataSource: {
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: function (readOptions) {
            readOptions.success(getDataFromDb(readOptions));
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Post some additional codes/details on your answer. Thanks for your hints.